# Trying to create an excel page using asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, asp.net-core

Help, i was ask to do this " use asp.net core to create an excel file"   ..
n.b im just getting started with asp.net core

Comment: Start by Googling EPPlus.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with VDWWD, easier way is to use EPPlus package. You can find lots of example on how to use this lib on the corresponding github:
https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/tree/master/SampleApp (look at the Sample*.cs files)

When you have more precise questions in case of issues with it, then recreate a new question on StackOverflow ^^

Comment: I forgot to say EPPlus is easy to find directly via nuget packages.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you want is create a file wich can be opened in Excel, the easier way is csvhelper https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/ o linq2excel https://github.com/mperdeck/LINQtoCSV
If you need something more complex, then yes, EPplus is your best choice.